# Can we lose our hats or it is a bug?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

I notice that I lost a hat, before I had 18 hats:

[image]

but now I can just see 17 hats.

[image]

I notice this because I open multiple tabs in my navigator.

My question: Can we lose our hats after we get them, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I general, no, you can't. We do occasionally realize that there's an error in how we're awarding hats so the hat is awarded incorrectly. When that happens we may clear the hats and re-award them to anyone who qualifies for the correct trigger.

While this is generally rare, we've had to do this twice for the Vexillologist hat to get it behaving correctly, so that may be the hat you lost. Yaakov mentioned this in the [Winter Bash chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56456059#56456059).